# Service Web with APNS serving two apps = two certificates?

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing a iOS app. This app has two targets (free version and premium version). Then I want to send push notifications throw my Service Web.

So, Do I need two certificates? Because my app (free or premium) uses the same Web Service and the same database. And when I want to send a push notification, now do I have to store and look if it's one version or another?

Can I use one certificate? Can I merge two certificates in one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use one certificate, since each certificate it tied to an App ID, and the App ID is different for each App (it contains the bundle ID of the App which is unique for each App).

You must use two certificates, which means your server will have to know which Device Token belongs to which App, and use the appropriate certificate. Perhaps, when you send the device token from your app to your server, you should send some additional info that indicates which App sent the token).